# AutoCompleteExtender is not working in user cotrole page in share point 2010 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are developing share point web application, in which threre are many user control(ascx) and aspx pages are there. My AutoCompleteExtender working fine in aspx page but when i put the code inot ascx(User control)page it doesnot working. Please help me...

My code in User controle for autocomplete search is:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" onkeyup="SetContextKey()" Style="width: 50px;"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCity"
                    MinimumPrefixLength="2" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000"
                    ServiceMethod="GetCity" ServicePath="~/Search.aspx" OnClientItemSelected="setCompanyMasterID"
                    UseContextKey="true" CompletionListCssClass="completionList" CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem"
                    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted" OnClientPopulated="onListPopulated">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Java Script and Css code is :

```
    function SetContextKey() {
        $find('<%=AutoCompleteExtender1.ClientID%>').set_contextKey($get("<%=txtTokenID.ClientID %>").value);
    }
    function setCompanyMasterID(source, eventargs) {

        var strIFSC = eventargs.get_value();
        alert(strIFSC);
        var Name = document.getElementById("<%=txtCity.ClientID %>").value;

        alert(Name);
    }
    function onListPopulated() {

        var completionList = $find('<%=AutoCompleteExtender1.ClientID%>').get_completionList();
        completionList.style.width = '200px';

        for (i = 0; i < completionList.childNodes.length; i++) {

            completionList.childNodes[i].title = completionList.childNodes[i]._value;
        }

    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .autocomplete_firstrow
    {
        background-color: Red;
        height: 20px;
    }
    .completionList
    {
        border: solid 1px Gray;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 3px;
        height: 220px;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #888888;
    }
    .listItem
    {
        color: #191919;
    }
    .itemHighlighted
    {
        background-color: #ADD6FF;
    }
</style>
```

And my GetCity method is in Search.aspx page becasue i did it after searching in nets...

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetCity(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
            GCIntegrationClient objGCIntegrationClient = new GCIntegrationClient();
            WcfGCIntegrationService.ServiceResult objServiceResult = new WcfGCIntegrationService.ServiceResult();
            objServiceResult = objGCIntegrationClient.GetIFSCCodeLOV_GetObjectData(contextKey, "", prefixText);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);

            List<string> CityNames = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < objServiceResult.UserData.IFSCCodeGrid.Length; i++)
            {
                CityNames.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.
                  CreateAutoCompleteItem(objServiceResult.UserData.IFSCCodeGrid[i].BankName, objServiceResult.UserData.IFSCCodeGrid[i].BankName));
            }
            return CityNames;
        }
```

Problem is that when i type the text then GetCity method didn't get fired....
but its get fired and working fine when it is on aspx page...
it is not working in ascx page....i have search many things but i didn't get appropriate answer...please help me.

Answer (score -1):

// do something like this at the end of your code

```
public class GetCity
{

    public GetCity()
    {
    }
    public GetCity(string Name, string Value)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }


}
```